# Sitecore menu items not working - javascript errors

Tags: sitecore

So I'm just starting to work in sitecore and for some reason none of menu options are working in Page Editor mode for the site that I'm working on.  We pretty much have the sitecore website and add some extra page content (MVC app files) to it.  I'm getting a variety of javascript errors.

In content Editor, if I click the Sitecore logo and click on Properties I get

```
TypeError: contentIframe.dialog is not a function
```

In page editor if I click on the blue components button I get:

```
TypeError: i.widget is not a function
```

I'm guessing maybe it's a conflict between jquery that we're using for this website and whatever Sitecore is using.  I think it's 7 - but I can't see it via the menu option :)

That guess could be wrong - it could in fact be a browser issue, but I've ensured Firefox is not blocking popups.  It doesn't work in Firefox, IE or Chrome though.

The weird thing is that no one else on the project is having this issue it's only on my computer.

Edit - I've also just tried re-installing (7.2) without any local code changes I still can't click on a page and go to Presentation, Details (Layout) - I get a TypeError: contentIframe.dialog is not a function

Edit 2 - I've noticed that I can use sitecore in the QA environment and the dialogs work fine there.  So it's something specific to my local build of the site we have (sitting on top of sitecore).  But the dialogs just throw jquery errors when I do stuff locally.  I was hoping it would be a browser setting but doesn't look like it.

Edit 3 - What I've tried this morning.

- Same thing happens in all browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) and I’ve cleared
  my browser cache I can access the QA site and the dialog appears as
  expected
- Copied across the QA site files, pointed my local Digital
  site in IIS to the new folder – dialogs don’t work
- Team member tried accessing the site from his machine (pointing to my IP address) and
  dialogs work for him
- I tried seeing if another local sitecore site dialogs were working – but the menu items for that are opening as new windows (so I’m guessing it’s a sitecore 7.2 feature that they appear as jquery dialogs??)

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct version for Sitecore and you don`t have any external plugins installed ? Sitecore`s jquery is runing in noconflict mode, so I doubt this is the cause of the issue.

Comment: I just installed Sitecore 7.2 from scratch.  We pretty much have a build process that dumps our website files on top of the sitecore ones.  So it's not vanilla Sitecore.

Comment: are you 100% sure the version of the Sitecore is 7.2 in the other environments?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my post with what I've tried this morning.

Comment: Did you use the Sitecore installer and if so did you select the MVC integration option? Can you also check the Network Panel in Chrome Dev Tools (press F12 and reload the page) and see if you are getting any 404 for script files.

Comment: @jammykam I used the Sitecore installer.  I didn't deselect the MVC integration option (I think it's selected by default).  My site is working with the MVC functionality. On loading the content editor I am getting 404 (Not found) for JqueryModalDialogs.html the url it's saying is: https://<mydomain>/sitecore/service/notfound.aspx?item=%2frejected-by-urlscan&user=sitecore%5cadmin&site=<myapp>  - Interestingly I don't get that 404 when I look at the qa site.

Comment: @jammykam also thanks for the details on bringing up the Chrome Dev tools :)

Comment: "item=%2frejected-by-urlscan" - do you have some sort of anti-virus or anti-malware software installed on your machine that could be blocking certain files?

Comment: @jammykam it's a work pc so I would have thought it was pretty standard.  Hopefully I can find something in my installed programs that stands out!  Thanks :)

Comment: @jammykam interestingly I noticed that in IE when going to my sitecore site I had a prompt down the bottom of my screen telling me that it was only showing secure items, so I selected to show all content. I no longer see the 404 errors in the network tab in developer tools.  But am still seeing this script error: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'widget' 
jquery.dialogextended-2.0.3.js, line 2 character 35

Comment: It sounds like you are using HTTPS locally? Are you able to test the site without this, or add it to the Trusted Sites list?

Comment: @jammykam Thanks for all your help - turns out there's a feature of IIS which is UrlScan.  That was blocking all my sitecore stuff!

Comment: Never heard of that module, but glad you solved the issue and hopefully help others searching in the future too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after googling for rejected-by-urlscan it turns out there's a program called UrlScan from microsoft that was blocking my dialogs.  Uninstalled that and I now have dialogs appearing for sitecore.  Very exciting :)

Comment: If you are unable to uninstall the program I resolved the issue by removing UrlScan from IIS. In the Home screen of IIS, click ISAPI Filters, right click on UrlScan and select Remove. Dialogs appearing once more.

Comment: In control panel > uninstall a program search for "urlscan". In my windows 7 machine the program name was "Microsoft URLScan Filter v3.1". Uninstalling it make the sitecore works as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is a problem with some browsers plugin. Sitecore is sensitive to scripts that are used(different versions of jquery or prototype.js). Plugins can inject scripts to HTML source of pages and it can cause errors.

Try to switch off all plugins at least at one browser and check the results.

Comment: Was happening in all browsers - including opera with no plugins.  Found the answer though!